# Zend locale get 12 or 24 hour time

Tags: zend-framework, locale

Any way to know if someone is using 24 hour or 12 hour time format with Zend locale. I would like to create a custom form and pass this information along for time input.

Thanks.

---

## Edit

Came up with this, if anyone knows of anything better let me know.

```
  private function is24HourFormat(){
    $localeObject = Zend_Registry::get('Locale');
    $locale = new Zend_Locale($localeObject);
    //create date for midnight
    $date = new Zend_Date('1980-1-1 24:00:00', false, $locale);

    //Should contain 12 if it's 12 hour time, otherwise 24 hour
    $time = $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT);
    return (strpos($time, "12") === false);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, unless someone has something better.

```
  private function is24HourFormat(){
    $localeObject = Zend_Registry::get('Locale');
    $locale = new Zend_Locale($localeObject);
    //create date for midnight
    $date = new Zend_Date('1980-1-1 24:00:00', false, $locale);

    //Should contain 12 if it's 12 hour time, otherwise 24 hour
    $time = $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT);
    return (strpos($time, "12") === false);
  }
```